# How to force unload a loaded servlet from Memory | Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, containers

I was curious about this particular condition during a servlet container's life. Suppose we have some memory allocated for the servlet container to load servlets(classes). Now at a particular time the memory is full and the container has to load a new servlet. In this condition, when a loaded container is taken out with whatever algorithm (I would be delighted to this as well if you could share), and is replaced with the required servlet. What exactly happens here? Is the destroy method called? The reason behind the curiosity is that, when replaced servlet is re-loaded again, is the init() method called the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlets are not unloaded from memory just because memory is full. In fact, Servlet objects typically are tiny and usually don't have any member variables because the state is completely stored in request/response objects handled by the servlet. Typically there is only one instance of each servlet allocated at any time.

This basically invalidates the rest of your question. A servlet is only unloaded when its webapplication is undeployed. When that happens, `destroy` is called, indeed. However, with an `OutOfMemory` condition, typically nothing can be done any more (as everything that can be garbage collected will have been collected), so you can't rely on `destroy` being called when there's no memory left. But, you'll have guessed it, when there's no more memory, `init` will be not be called again, because there's no space left to initialize more objects.

When a webapplication is redeployed, `destroy` is called on the undeploying servlet, and `init` will be called before the first use of the newly deployed servlet.

The algorithm that determines which objects are freed up is your garbage collector's algorithm (configurable). But it will only collect unused ("garbage", "unreferenced") objects, *not* random Servlets that haven't been used in a while.